# Installing only 64 bit packages via the R command line

Tags: r, installation, package

I recently upgraded to R 2.15.1 and am having trouble installing packages from the command line.

I tried using:

```
R --arch x86_64 CMD INSTALL package_1.0.tar.gz
```

But R tries to install the i386 version - and then that requires a 32 bit version of a dependent package that I do not have installed. However the 64 bit version of the package *is* available - yet, the entire install process fails.

I would've thought that specifying the architecture would prevent R from trying to install a 32 bit version. Am I missing something obvious? (This was not an issue on 2.14)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What OS?

On my computer, `R CMD INSTALL --help` suggests the `--no-multiarch` flag.

Comment: This fixed the `Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava'` that popped up on windows when installing packages that depended on rJava when I only had the x64 JRE installed.